# Disable USB mass storage access on client machines

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012

This might not be a new question for this forum but for me it is very critical.

I am having a network of 10 PCs, one is having Windows Server 2012 and Others having Windows 7/Windows 8.1. The server is a Domain controller. What I need is to disable USB mass storage access on client PCs(Win 7/8.1), however i need to allow USB keyboard and mouse accessible on those machines.

I followed [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4f135025-9870-4f43-aff5-f5ccc8b40220/block-usb-drive-via-group-policy-but-keyboard-mouse-printers-and-usb-datacard-work?forum=winserverGP)
but still not getting the result. This works for server only not for client pcs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

You have to do this steps as bellow:

1. Go to the client machine and
2. go to start button and type in to search box `gpedit.msc`
3. then your group policy window will open
4. left side of window - search `Administrative Templates` and double click on it
5. then click on `System`
6. next you will see `Removable Storage Access` just click on it
7. then you will see lots of group policy name
8. see the `All Removable Storage Access: Deny All Access`
9. double click on it and select the option `Enable` and click on OK button
10. you will success to block USB of client

Comment: this method as explained applies only on win 8 or 10 etc.. so  any work around for the windows xp SP3

Answer (score 2):

The link you shared has this comment:
you can use the below GPO.
User Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ System \ Removable Storage Access \ All Removable Storage classes: Deny all access.

Have you tried it?